# Remove required fields from magento admin panel

Tags: php

My client ask me to remove the required option from some fields in the product form from magento admin panel, because he don't want to fill this fields.

I need to say to magento that the field Short Description is not required, how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - make the field "company" required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456794/magento-make-the-field-company-required)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Login into magento admin backend.

Go to **Catalog** => **Attributes** => **Manage Attributes**

Then find the attribute of the product (in your case `short_description`) and click it.

Then set `Values Required` to `No`

Comment: Ahh! 20 seconds late :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` search for the attribute you need to change (in your case Short description) and set the field `Required` to `No`